# Are there any connections between the "backfitting" algorithim for GAM and backpropogation in neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, generalized-additive-model, backpropagation

Are there any connections between back-fitting in GAM and backpropogation in neural networks? Are they similar processes?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backfitting_algorithm

Comment: I think you could give a look at projection-pursuit regression (Friedman, 1981) and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_pursuit_regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no connection between the two.
The **backfitting** algorithm that is used to fit GAMs, iteratively improves the estimator $\hat {f_j}$ by subtracting the contribution of each predictor $j$ from the response $y$ that is influenced by all, say '$p$' predictors, followed by smoothing using optimal bandwidth, which is yet solving a linear equation although you are working with a nonlinear $f_j$.

On the other hand, **backpropagation** algorithm which is used to find weights in a neural network works through by computing gradients(derivatives, these do not exist for the *linear* equation that backfitting is solving) of *non-linear* functions and propagating the results via chain rule.

Hope it helps!